# Invalid URL while trying to download file with requests , python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Its been hours that I am trying to download a file which is being played everywhere.

But as I try to get file by requests in python I get this error:

InvalidURL: Invalid URL 'https:\\scontent.cdninstagram.com\v\t66.30100-16\122009079_349367310880138_909876289331831527_n.mp4?_nc_cat=103&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=9a5d50&efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6ImlnLXhwdmRzLmNsaXBzLmMyLUMzLmRhc2hfdnA5ZXZlXzVfdjEifQ==&_nc_ohc=2vJyXzH4oP8AX9FUxpd&_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com&oh=00_AfDl7RGXZjG2dwJ8q0WD3rSQdQ0CBC2xf03JrEOIx0eSrw&oe=654971FE': No host supplied

---

```
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'
}
url=r"https:\\scontent.cdninstagram.com\v\t66.30100-16\122009079_349367310880138_909876289331831527_n.mp4?_nc_cat=103&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=9a5d50&efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6ImlnLXhwdmRzLmNsaXBzLmMyLUMzLmRhc2hfdnA5ZXZlXzVfdjEifQ==&_nc_ohc=2vJyXzH4oP8AX9FUxpd&_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com&oh=00_AfDl7RGXZjG2dwJ8q0WD3rSQdQ0CBC2xf03JrEOIx0eSrw&oe=654971FE"
print(url)
req_DL = requests.get(url,headers=headers, verify=False, timeout=10)
with open(filename,'wb') as w:
    w.write(req_DL.content)
```

I tried to download a file with python and I get this error

Answer (score 0):

You have `url` incorrect (should be `/`, not `\`):

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"
}
url = r"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/v/t66.30100-16/122009079_349367310880138_909876289331831527_n.mp4?_nc_cat=103&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=9a5d50&efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6ImlnLXhwdmRzLmNsaXBzLmMyLUMzLmRhc2hfdnA5ZXZlXzVfdjEifQ==&_nc_ohc=2vJyXzH4oP8AX9FUxpd&_nc_ht=scontent.cdninstagram.com&oh=00_AfDl7RGXZjG2dwJ8q0WD3rSQdQ0CBC2xf03JrEOIx0eSrw&oe=654971FE"

filename = "file.mp4"

req_DL = requests.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False, timeout=10)
with open(filename, "wb") as w:
    w.write(req_DL.content)
```

Downloads `file.mp4`:

```
$ ls -alF *mp4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5587597 nov  3 21:15 file.mp4
```